# How can I use Raspberry pi gpio setup and pwm commands in __init__ function of a class?

Tags: python, oop, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am new at object oriented programming.I am working with Raspberry pi and I am building many classes which have different GPIO pins. I don’t know how to build setup and pwm comands. All of them should stay out of the classes or should I put them in **init** function for each class? How will it change for OOP in **init** function? Can you show me an example on this code?

```
GPIO.setup(33, GPIO.OUT)
pwmservo=GPIO.PWM(33,50)
pwmservo.start(6)

class zmove(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def update(self,angle):
        duty=float(angle)/10.0+2.5
        pwmservo.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
        time.sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: GPIO Zero has `Servo` and `AngularServo` classes: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#servo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: gpio setup and pwm commands in **init** function of a class?

```
class PWMServo:
    """
    Base class doing setup and get PWM instance
    """
    def __init__(self, pin):
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
        self.pwm = GPIO.PWM(pin, 50)
        self.pwm.start(6)

    def change_duty_cycle(self, duty):
        self.pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
        time.sleep(0.3)

class ZMove(PWMServo):
    """
    Inherit from class PWMServo
    ZMove use PIN 33
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(pin=33)
        self.pwm.start(6)

    def update(self,angle):
        duty=float(angle)/10.0+2.5
        self.change_duty_cycle(duty)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zmove = ZMove()

    zmove.update(45.0)

    # Or, call direct
    zmove.change_duty_cycle(45.0/10.0+2.5)
```